# Exporting query from Azure Data Explorer to Power BI fails for Application Insights Cluster

Tags: powerbi, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I managed to query my AI telemetrydata from Azure data explorer specifying the cluster as :

https://ade.applicationinsights.io/subscriptions/MYSUBSCRIPTION-GUID/resourcegroups/MY-RG/providers/microsoft.insights/components/MY-AINAME

[Successful query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMNXc.png)

When I use the Export to Power BI I get the following script

let
Source = AzureDataExplorer.Contents("https://ade.applicationinsights.io/subscriptions/MYSUBSCRIPTION-GUID/resourcegroups/MY-RG/providers/microsoft.insights/components/MY-AINAME", "uptakesim", "customEvents#(lf)| where timestamp > ago(1d)", [Timeout = #duration(0,0,4,0)])
in
Source

When I try to run that exported query in PowerBI I get the following error :

[Power BI error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcNvF.png)

For some reason the sign in fails and does not show any prompt to login.

If I end the url at /microsoft.insights

https://ade.applicationinsights.io/subscriptions/MY_SUBSCRIPTION/resourcegroups/MY-RG/providers/microsoft.insights

removing
/components/MY-AINAME

the login works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I tried the same and got the same issue while importing Application insights data from azure data explorer (Kusto). Refer the fourth point in the [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/visualize-power-bi-archive#connect-to-azure-data-explorer) for the cluster format to be used while connecting Data explorer cluster in Power BI. We can import only Kusto cluster data using azure data explorer in power BI.
  [image]

Instead, you can follow the below approach to read data from application insights data in power BI.

- Open the application insights log in azure portal.
- Type the query and run it.
- Then click on Export and select Power BI (as an M Query)
  [image]
- This will give the query in a `.txt` file.
- Then in Power BI desktop, Click get data-> Blank Query

[image]

- Click the Advanced editor. Replace the sample code with the power query from the exported file.
  [image]
- Click Done in the advanced editor window.
- Data will be loaded in the power BI Power Query editor.

[image]

- While exporting from application insights log, you can also choose Power BI (new Dataset). Refer the [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/create-dataset-log-analytics) for more details.

**Reference:**
[Log Analytics integration with Power BI and Excel - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-powerbi)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that solved all my problems